# Load Application on Windows Startup Before Login

Tags: vb.net, winforms, startup

I'm writing a VB.NET application that I want to load at Windows start up before the user logs in. It's going to run on a server and launch other process and kill and restart them as needed to get around a memory leak issue. It also needs to have a GUI to view the current status of the processes its managing.

Now, I can get the application to load when the user logs in but that's not very helpful because the server could reboot for some reason and no user would be logged on, but this application still needs to run in the background.

How do I do this? Do I need to write it as a service, or is there another way? I tried writing a WinForms app but it wouldn't load until after the user logs in.

Comment: Break your application up into two separate components. One will be a WinForms application which provides the GUI and let the user  interact with it. The other will be a Windows Service which can start before the login.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a service. Also, probably best to write a second app that will interact with the service and provide a GUI to control what it does.

Comment: That's what I figured. I never worked with services before. Could you update your answer with a good link or two about working with Windows services? I need to send commands with integer parameters to the service and poll the service for a status update in the form of a `DataTable` object.